# Calculate a Guassian standardized variable in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, mean

I wrote this script in GEE to calculate NDVI as well as the NDVI mean and standard deviation.

```
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

// This is the Sentinel 2 collection
var S2_collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2019-12-31') 
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',1))
  .map(maskS2clouds)
  .median();
                  
var composite = S2_collection.clip(geometry);
var composite = composite.toFloat()
// Add map layers
Map.addLayer(composite , {bands: ['B11', 'B8', 'B4']}, "composite");
                  

//Compute  NDVI 
var nir = S2_collection.select('B8');
var red = S2_collection.select('B4');
var ndvi = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red));
var ndvi = ndvi.clip(geometry);
// Add map layers
Map.addLayer(ndvi, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['black', 'yellow', 'green']}, 'continuous NDVI');

// Compute the mean and stdev of NDVI
var mean_ndvi = ndvi.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 10
});
var sd_ndvi = ndvi.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 10
});
print(mean_ndvi);
print(sd_ndvi);
```

I need to calculate the Gaussian variable of this index such as:
([NDVI - NDVI(mean)] / [NDVI_sd])

By using the reducer for mean and std dev, I create a dictionary
, but if I want to visualize the mean and sd map results, I get the error:

> Cannot add an object of type  to the map

How can I calculate mean and sd for each pixel of my image and calculate this index and map it?

[Link to my script](https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/391bddf34a2f272482eb174e59c5c3fe)

Update to my question:

1. I need the NDVI_gaussian value for a single image of 9th February 2019 over this geometry area:

   0: [16.53793865386438,40.509788101097925]

   1: [16.552594243921753,40.509788101097925]

   2: [16.552594243921753,40.51740638148722]

   3: [16.53793865386438,40.51740638148722]

   4: [16.53793865386438,40.509788101097925]

and it should look like this:

[image]

And 2) I need the NDVI guassian formula in the February–November 2019 period, which should look like this:

[image]

And the index is defined as:

[image]

Comment: `mean_ndvi` and `sd_ndvi`, that's the mean/standard deviation of all pixels within your geometry, based on your slightly confusingly named median composite `S2_collection`. That's what you intended to do? Those are two numbers, so you cannot put them on a map (or at least, they're not very interesting to see on a map). Or did you want to calculate mean and standard deviation separately for every pixel in your geometry, based on your two year date range?

Comment: oh you are right.  No I do not want to calculate the mean/sd of all  pixels within geometry. I am looking for the second option. I intended to calculate mean/sd for each pixel in that period, map them for each pixel, and then calculate the formula I wrote above as (NDVI - NDVI_mean) / (NDVI_sd) for each pixel and finally map this index over all region.

Comment: Do you want to apply this formula to every image in a collection of NDVI values, or to the median NDVI?

Comment: I need both actually. The paper that I read it from says the index between 2017 and 2019, So I do not know if it means for each image separately or teh median of all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a couple of changes:

- Increased the `CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE` limit to `10`, to make sure you get imagery for your date of interest.
- Switched out the cloud masking to use the `COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY` collection. It's slower but better.
- Limited the date range used to calculate the statistics, not to include the landslide. When the landslide is part of the statistics, the pixel values afterwards wouldn't be an anomaly.

The below doesn't replicate the results exactly, but at least highlights the landslide.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  [16.53793865386438,40.509788101097925],
  [16.552594243921753,40.509788101097925],
  [16.552594243921753,40.51740638148722],
  [16.53793865386438,40.51740638148722],
  [16.53793865386438,40.509788101097925]
])
var anomalyThreshold = -2
var cloudThreshold = 30

var filter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.bounds(geometry),
  ee.Filter.date('2017-01-01', '2020-01-01')
)

// Uses slower but better cloud masking
var ndviCollection = ee.ImageCollection(
    ee.Join.saveFirst('cloudProbability').apply({
        primary: ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
          .filter(filter)
          .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10)), // Increased the limit, to include imagery for your date
        secondary: ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY')
          .filter(filter),
        condition: ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'system:index', rightField: 'system:index'})
    })
).map(toNdvi)

var stats = ndviCollection 
  .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2019-02-01') // Maybe limit this date range to some stable reference period?
  .reduce(
    ee.Reducer.mean()
        .combine(ee.Reducer.stdDev(), null, true)
  )
var gaussianCollection = ndviCollection.map(toGaussian)
var anomalyCount = gaussianCollection
  .filterDate('2019-02-01', '2019-12-01')
  .map(function (image) {
    return image.updateMask(image.lte(anomalyThreshold))
  })
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.count())
  .unmask(0)

var image = gaussianCollection
  .filterDate(ee.Date('2019-02-09').getRange('day'))
  .mosaic()

Map.addLayer(image, {min: -5, max: 5, palette: '#67001f, #b2182b, #d6604d, #f4a582, #fddbc7, #f7f7f7, #d1e5f0, #92c5de, #4393c3, #2166ac, #053061'}, 'image', true)
Map.addLayer(anomalyCount, {min: 0, max: 52, palette: '#042333, #2c3395, #744992, #b15f82, #eb7958, #fbb43d, #e8fa5b'}, 'anomaly count')
Map.centerObject(geometry)


function toGaussian(ndvi) {
  return ee.Image()
    .expression('(ndvi - ndvi_mean) / ndvi_stdDev', {
      ndvi: ndvi,
      ndvi_mean: stats.select('ndvi_mean'),
      ndvi_stdDev: stats.select('ndvi_stdDev')
    })
    .copyProperties(ndvi, ndvi.propertyNames())
}

function toNdvi(image) {
  var cloudFree = ee.Image(image.get('cloudProbability')).lt(cloudThreshold)
  return image.updateMask(cloudFree)
    .normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
    .float()
    .rename('ndvi')
    .copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames())
}

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60')
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))
  return image.updateMask(mask)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d7cc2331bbfa8e2ea81db30a47aaf198

Comment: Thanks very much @Daniel. I explain better my objective. I read in a paper that for studying the land cover changes after a landslide, it is helpful to map NDVI variations before and after the event since vegetation changes due to landslide. They also suggested that after mapping NDVI, if we calculate NDVI_mean & NDVI_std dev for each pixel and then calculate the gaussian index as the formula I wrote, we can observe the changes much better. So I managed to map NDVI over the map, but I wrote a dictionary instead of an image and calculated those values as a number for the whole image.

Comment: Thanks for your script. 'var Stats' reduces the imageCollection to mean and stdDev for each pixel, and then you used 'toGaussian' to apply the formula, is it correct? The vaules of 'gausian of median' and 'median of gausian' are the same, so did you apply the formula to the median NDVI? If I want to apply the formula to only one image of the collection, how should I change it?

Comment: `stats` and `toGaussian()` - you're correct. The two layers, `gausian of median` calculates the median ndvi and calculates the gausian of that, while `median of gaussian` calculates the gausian for every image in the collection and takes the median of that. Same result, yes, I just wanted to highlight these different approaches. Your last question, which image do you want to apply the formula to?

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel. How can I add an image in the comments? I just read the paper and the result of our script is not the same as what it should be. Can I send you the paper or an image of it in some way ?

Comment: You cannot, but please update your question with more details.

Comment: Thanks again. I updated my question. Please have a look. Maybe this way I can show what I exactly need.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks very much. I understood the changes. The map 'image' shows for one single date, while map 'anomalycount' shows this period: '2019-02-01, 2019-12-01' after the landslide. The landslide happened in January 2019, so this period does not include that date in order to show its anomaly better. Is it correct? I do not understand the 'var anomalyThreshold = -2'. How is it determined?

Comment: First layer - correct. Second layer shows the number of anomalous observations, i.e. which have a value `<= -2`. That threshold comes from a screenshot in your question :-). The statistics are calculated for dates between `2017-01-01` and `2019-02-01` to exclude the landslide.

Comment: Yes that is right. Thanks again. I also did not know about the COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY collection.

Comment: It happened on 25 Jan 2019, so should I change the second date from 2019-02-01 to another date before 25/01/2019? Because now it is getting included in the period, right?

Comment: Sure. Remember that the end in a date range in exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the following expression:

```
(ndvi.subtract(mean_ndvi)).divide(sd_ndvi)
```

But, since both outputs are dictionaries, convert it to images:

```
(ndvi.subtract(mean_ndvi.toImage())).divide(sd_ndvi.toImage())
```

---

Appliying to each date:

```
var geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* shown: false */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[16.529551494306034, 40.525518691809275],
          [16.529551494306034, 40.505160304711104],
          [16.566973674481815, 40.505160304711104],
          [16.566973674481815, 40.525518691809275]]], null, false);

/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var S2_collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2019-12-31') 
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',1))
  .map(maskS2clouds);

var ndvi = S2_collection.map(function(img){return img.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])});
var ndvi = ndvi.map(function(img){return img.clip(geometry)});

var mean_ndvi = ndvi.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
var sd_ndvi = ndvi.reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev());
var zscore = ndvi.map(function(img){return (img.subtract(mean_ndvi)).divide(sd_ndvi)});

Map.addLayer(mean_ndvi, {}, 'mean NDVI');
Map.addLayer(sd_ndvi, {}, 'sd NDVI');
Map.addLayer(zscore, {}, 'z-score');
Map.centerObject(geometry);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I modified my script : https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/eab3ffe805e27105fa87243d2d0eb888,   is there a way to calculate the mean and sd without dictionaries and adding each as images and then used the expression you mentioned? Thanks

Comment: You can display both outputs with `Map.addLayer(mean_ndvi.toImage().clip(geometry), {}, 'mean');` and `Map.addLayer(sd_ndvi.toImage().clip(geometry), {}, 'sd');`. Both will be added as black images since there is no color palette associated. There are other approaches but for computing temporal mean and sd for each pixel, which is not the case of your code, although I don't know your objective here

Comment: My final objective is to map the guassian index I mentioned and classify it based on its values.

Comment: If you are going to use several layers and a ML model I get it, but I see no difference using this index or using the NDVI values for single layer classification. For ML models, z-score is the most used standardization method and it's the same index you are using here, but it's normally used for NNs or when you use many input layers. for RF or other models, isn't needed

Comment: Thanks Aldo, I read from a paper to calculate this index instead of the simple NDVI for better understanding the land cover changes. So I need to calculate NDVI, NDVI_mean, NDVI_std dev for each pixel of the map during that period and then calculate this index and map it. Do you think that by the expression you wrote (with converting to images), this objective can be achieved? Because as for the other comment by Daniel Wiell, I am afraid if this dictionary is calculating the mean/sd for all image and resulting in just one number,because I don't want that. I want mean/sd/index for every pixel.

Comment: Daniel is right, that's my point as well. For a single image it won't work. I edited my answer. Your issue is using `.median()`, that convert the imageCollection to a image removing any date property, hence, the ability to compute mean or sd for every pixel. Now is with the function you posted